# Angular factory.factory is not a function

Tags: angular

I am working on a recipe app with angular, and trying to set up communication with backend services using HTTP. I have been following along with angular documentation to set this up, here is the link https://angular.io/guide/http#sending-data-to-a-server. When I add in the code to make a POST request, I get the following error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: factory.factory is not a function
TypeError: factory.factory is not a function
    at getNodeInjectable (core.js:3913)
    at searchTokensOnInjector (core.js:3849)
    at getOrCreateInjectable (core.js:3771)
    at Module.ɵɵdirectiveInject (core.js:13730)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.FormComponent_Factory [as factory] (form.component.ts:14)
    at getNodeInjectable (core.js:3913)
    at instantiateRootComponent (core.js:7837)
    at createRootComponent (core.js:18351)
    at ComponentFactory$1.create (core.js:22287)
    at ViewContainerRef.createComponent (core.js:10127)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:798)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:750)
    at zone-evergreen.js:860
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:27126)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:398)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:569)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:484)
    at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:1621)
```

I am not sure how to fix this error, as I have been trying to figure it out for quite a while. Here is my code that initiates the POST request:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
    import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
    import { Validators } from '@angular/forms';
    import { Addedrecipes } from './addedsoups';
    import { RecipesService } from './recipes.service';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-form',
      templateUrl: './form.component.html',
      providers: [RecipesService],
      styleUrls: ['./form.component.css']
    })
    export class FormComponent implements OnInit {
    
      sections = ['Bread', 'Soup', 'Cakes'];
    
      recipe = { name: '', ingredients: '', description: '', section: this.sections[0] };
    
      Form: FormGroup;
      addedrecipes: any;
    
      constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private recipesService: RecipesService) { }
    
      ngOnInit() {
        this.Form = new FormGroup({
          name: new FormControl(this.recipe.name, [
            Validators.required,
            Validators.minLength(1)
          ]),
          ingredients: new FormControl(this.recipe.ingredients, [
            Validators.required,
            Validators.minLength(10)
          ]),
          description: new FormControl(this.recipe.description, [
            Validators.required,
            Validators.minLength(20)
          ]),
          section: new FormControl(this.recipe.section, Validators.required)
        })
    
      }
      add(name: string, description: string, ingredients: string): void {
        name = name.trim();
        description = description.trim();
        ingredients = ingredients.trim();
        if (!name || !description || !ingredients) {
          return;
    
        }
    
    
        // The server will generate the id for this new hero
        const newRecipe: Addedrecipes = { name, description, ingredients } as Addedrecipes;
        console.log("this works");
        this.recipesService
          .addRecipe(newRecipe)
          .subscribe(recipe => this.addedrecipes.push(recipe)); 
      }
    
      onSubmit() {
        // TODO: Use EventEmitter with form value
        console.warn(this.Form.value);
      }
    }
```

Here is my service that makes the request:

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
    
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
    
    import { Addedrecipes } from './addedsoups';
    import { HttpErrorHandler, HandleError } from '../http-error-handler.service';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    
    
     const httpOptions = { 
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json',
        Authorization: 'my-auth-token'
      })
    };
    // @NgModule({
    //   declarations: [],
    //   imports: [BrowserModule],
    //   providers: [HttpErrorHandler],
    //   bootstrap: []
    // })
    // @Injectable({
    //   providedIn: 'root',
    // }) 
    @NgModule({
      providers: [HttpErrorHandler]
    }) 
    
    @Injectable ()
    export class RecipesService {
      recipeUrl = 'api/recipe';  // URL to web api
      private handleError: HandleError;
        
      constructor(
        private http: HttpClient,
        httpErrorHandler: HttpErrorHandler) {   
        this.handleError = httpErrorHandler.createHandleError('RecipesService');
       {   }
       
    }
    
    
    addRecipe(addedrecipes: Addedrecipes): Observable<Addedrecipes> {
      return this.http.post< Addedrecipes>(this.recipeUrl, addedrecipes, httpOptions)
        .pipe(
          catchError(this.handleError("addRecipe", addedrecipes))
        );
    }
    }
```

Any ideas on how to fix the occurring error? Any ideas/suggestions are appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's form.component.ts's line 14? That's where the error is.

Comment: Also have you provided the service in the module where your component is declared? I notice you're not using providedIn: root.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, the form.component.ts is the file name of the first code sample I provided. After uncommenting providedIn: root, I got a new error

Comment: Uncaught Error: Angular JIT compilation failed: '@angular/compiler' not loaded!
 JIT compilation is discouraged for production use-cases! Consider AOT mode instead.
 Did you bootstrap using '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic' or '@angular/platform-server'?
Alternatively provide the compiler with 'import "@angular/compiler";' before bootstrapping.

Comment: Does that mean I have to import one of those modules in my service?

Comment: Did you restart your server? if you're using ivy then I find it sometimes gets confused when you add new modules/provide new services in an adhoc fashion.

Comment: Is that `@NgModule` declaration in your service commented out or not? Because it shouldn't be there -- it's a service not a module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments and the code, you've got a bit of a mess.

First off, your service should not have an `@NgModule` declaration: it's a service, not a module. Further, since your service isn't `providedIn: "root"`, you need to actually provide it in your module.

Assuming AppModule is where this component and this service both live, you should have an app.module.ts something like this:

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [FormComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  providers: [HttpErrorHandler, RecipesService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Your form.component.ts is fine as far as I can tell.

In your recipes.service.ts, you need to omit the NgModule declaration entirely:

```js
@Injectable ()
export class RecipesService {
  recipeUrl = 'api/recipe';  // URL to web api
  private handleError: HandleError;
        
  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
              httpErrorHandler: HttpErrorHandler) {   
    this.handleError = httpErrorHandler.createHandleError('RecipesService');
  }
    
    
  addRecipe(addedrecipes: Addedrecipes): Observable<Addedrecipes> {

    const httpOptions = { 
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json',
        Authorization: 'my-auth-token'
      })
    };
    return this.http.post< Addedrecipes>(this.recipeUrl, addedrecipes, httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError("addRecipe", addedrecipes))
      );
  }
}
```

The reason I'm pretty sure this is what's going on is your error message. If you look at that stack trace, it's actually complaining about the injected dependencies -- the line in the stack trace that refers to your actual code is `NodeInjectorFactory.FormComponent_Factory [as factory] (form.component.ts:14)`. This indicates that there's nothing wrong with your API call itself ... or at least, it isn't even getting to that point. The problem is something with how you've declared your service and presented it to Angular to be injected.

The easiest way to provide services is via the default. When you generate a new service with the Angular CLI, it will create a service that's available globally:

```js
@Injectable({ 
  providedIn: "root" 
})
```

If you don't want your service available globally, you can remove this as you have in your example. However as a side effect, wherever you want to actually use that service you have to explicitly provide it using the `providers` array in the module declaration.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was very helpful, and fixed my problem, thank you for your patience as I am new to angular